# about queue in C++

Tags: c++, queue, push

I used push in queue to add this element to my queue but it hasn't worked!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,k,tamp;
    cin >> n>> k;
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> > q;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> tamp;
        q.push(tamp);
    }
    while(q.top() < k && q.size() > 1)
    {
        tamp = q.top() * 1;
        cout << q.top() << endl;
        q.pop();
        tamp += q.top() * 2;
        cout << q.top() << endl;
        q.pop();

        cout << tamp << endl;

        q.push(tamp);
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            cout << "p=" << q.top() << endl;
            q.pop();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my test:

1. 8 90
2. 13 47 74 12 89 74 18 38

it will change into 12 13 18 38 47 74 74 89.
and `tamp=12+13*2=38` and push this into queue but the queue just have 18 38 47 74 74 89!!!
Help me and thank you for watching this!!!

Comment: `k`? WTH is `k`? I see no `k` being defined in your code. Nor `xet`. If you're going to post code, make sure it's the *right* code, that will compile and run.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I forget to delete this!! tks for your comment

Comment: I have changed it. If you have free time, check it again! I appreciate that!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an outer loop that does

```
while(q.top() < k && q.size() > 1)
```

So, clearly you expect to loop a few times, based on q's content. But then, you do:

```
while(!q.empty())
{
    cout << "p=" << q.top() << endl;
    q.pop();
}
```

which will empty the queue. So, it won't loop.

Please state what you are trying to do.